How to set up REDbox functionality using Parallel Redundancy Protocol on linux?
I am trying to create a Redbox functionality on a Linux box with three interfaces using PRP redundancy feature. I was able to configure the PRP and am able to verify that it works when the initiation to destination is from the host - DAN functionality.
I am trying to see if I can bridge port-C to a configured PRP interface for adding port C.
Does the prp interface is a full feature Linux interface so that it can be added to a bridge ?
When I am looking at the node table - I see MAC of vDAN's on both boxes but I don't see those MAC's even coming out in the supervision frame - thus when a SAN or a DAN replies to ARP related to a vDAN -they don't go up the prp stack - ARP can't be resolved and thus Redbox functionality doesn't work.
Is there something I am missing here.
This is what I have tried...same thing (different MAC) on two boxes......so far
ip link set eth1 down
ip link set eth2 down
ip link set dev eth1 address aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
ip link set dev eth2 address aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
ip link add name br01 type bridge
ip link set eth3 master br01
ip link add name prp0 type hsr slave1 eth1 slave2 eth2 supervision 45 proto 1
ip link set br01 up
ip link set eth1 up
ip link set eth2 up
ip link set eth3 up
ip link set prp0 master br01
ip link set prp0 up

Any help in this will be greatly appreciate.
Thanks
